# AWS ApiGateway VPC Link vs HTTP Proxy integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-gateway

Well, I'm creating a AWS ApiGateway and I can't understand when I should use integration type HTTP_PROXY or VPC_LINK, both ask me URL to proxy.

I searched about it but can't found any concrect and simple example, when use one or other ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

API Gateway REST API allows proxy integrations to other endpoints via two methods.

- [HTTP_PROXY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html) is for Public API endpoints only.
- [VPC_LINK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vpc-links.html) allows us to integrate API Gateway with Private Endpoints exposed via NLB (not ALB)

API Gateway HTTP API also supports both public and private integrations

- [HTTP URI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-http.html): For public endpoints.
- [Private Resource](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/configuring-private-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway-http-apis/): For NLB, ALB or CloudMap

Comment: Can I use AWS Apigateway REST API with CloudMap ?

Comment: I think we can use HTTP_PROXY on services with in non-vpc namespace. I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm setting up an HTTP AWS API Gateway with Lambda integrations.
But I'm running into the issue Lambda integration requires `integration_type = AWX_PROXY`
But it’s incompatible with `connection_type = "VPC_LINK"` which requires integration_type = "HTTP_PROXY".
I can change to `connection_type = "INTERNET"` to make these compatible. But is this the only way?